# BackgroundWorker Thread in IIS7 - FAIL!

Tags: iis, iis-7, backgroundworker

Just wondering if anyone has had any trouble using a BackgroundWorker Thread in a site running under IIS 7 in Integrated Pipeline mode?

I am trying to use such a beast to update the database schema (admin function, obviously), and it works perfectly in Cassini, but when I deploy to IIS 7, the thread gets about one line of code in and silently ends.  Is there a way to tell why a thread ended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably an exception. Perhaps you're running with different set of rights between the two environments.

Comment: Ah... the penny drops!  Of course, Cassini runs under my user account (a machine admin), while the IIS7 process is a non-privileged user.  Now why didn't I think of that?  Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know but I have to ask: why do you use BackgroundWorker in first place? Its main purpose is to ease the threading on UI elements.
Instead why don't you use a "normal" thread or any other non-UI mechanism?

Comment: Fair call - probably too much time working in WPF and WinForms apps, I guess.  These things can be habit-forming...

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use BackgroundWorker, Thomas from ASP.NET team just posted some information about executing code in separate threads in ASP.NET:  http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx